# How to preserve helm project search results to iterate through them

Tags: spacemacs, helm, search

I am using spacemacs with vim bindings and doing a search project-wide for something like `while \(` with `SPC s p`. I get the results in a helm buffer and can enter transient state to navigate them, but once I open one of the listed files, the search disappears and `C-o` does not get me back to it. I am forced to repeat the search.

For doing project-wide refactors this is pretty inconvenient. In my situation it's not a simple search and replace. I have to inspect each use and determine if I need to refactor.

Is there any way to preserve the search results so I can go through the results and return to them?

I saw in the help menu `C-c o` to open results in a new buffer, but that seems to just open a new buffer with the same file I was on, not the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can toggle `helm-follow-mode` using `C-c C-f` within a helm buffer, then when cycling through helm you will see previews of the results. You can switch to the results buffer by typing `M-1` and then switch back to the helm buffer by typing `M-2` or `SPC w w`.

Also, after you have closed the helm buffer, e.g. by selecting/visiting one of its results by pressing `RET` on it, you can use `M-x helm-resume` or `SPC r l` to reopen the last results in helm.

Comment: Very nice! I particularly like `helm-resume`, as I could even use it without `helm-follow-mode`. Where did you find the `M-1` bindings documented? I didn't find them in the [helm layer docs](https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+completion/helm/README.html).

Comment: I don't remember where I found that, I think either someone told me about it, or I just discovered it at some point as an alternative to `SPC 1..2` etc. (which does not work in helm of course). It is a general global keybinding, but I can not find any place where it is documented.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for checking!